# What is the right way to use xpath on nodejs + xpath-Module if you search in subnodes?

Tags: node.js, xpath, xmldom

I use XMLDOM + XPath to find XMLs nodes in this script:

```js
var DOMParser = require("xmldom").DOMParser;
var xpath = require("xpath");

let data = `<start>
    <b1 id="111"><c1 id="333">ccc</c1></b1>
<b1 id="222">bbb</b1>
</start>`;

let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data);
let nodes = xpath.select("//b1", doc);

// let doc2 = new DOMParser().parseFromString(nodes[0].toString());
let doc2 = nodes[0];
console.log("doc2.toString: ", doc2.toString());

let nodes2 = xpath.select("b1", doc2);

console.log("nodes found by xpath 'b1': ", nodes2.toString());

if (nodes2.length > 0) {
  console.log("id = " + nodes2[0].getAttribute("id"));
}

nodes2 = xpath.select("b1/c1", doc2);

console.log("nodes found by xpath 'b1/c1': ", nodes2.toString());

if (nodes2.length > 0) {
  console.log("id = " + nodes2[0].getAttribute("id"));
}

nodes2 = xpath.select("c1", doc2);

console.log("nodes found by xpath 'c1': ", nodes2.toString());

if (nodes2.length > 0) {
  console.log("id = " + nodes2[0].getAttribute("id"));
}
```

I want make a list of `<b1>` nodes and then get the id-value of the node.

The XPath pattern `b1/c1` don't work but the `c1` does.

If I change from search in a subnode

```js
let doc2 = nodes[0];
```

to search in complete XML Document

```js
let doc2 = new DOMParser().parseFromString(nodes[0].toString());
```

the `b1/c1` pattern work!

Why `b1/c1` don't work in case one?

Try:

```
echo "<b1 id=\"111\"><c1 id=\"333\">ccc</c1></b1>" | xmllint  --xpath b1/c1 -
```

find:

```
<c1 id="333">ccc</c1>
```

On a plain XML the xpath pattern work fine, why not on subnodes from XMLDOM?

Or try in:

https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: I have no idea what's the point of your `doc2.toString()`. You already have a document, it makes no sense at all to convert it back to string.

Comment: First I try find my node in one node of the subnodelist. The xpath 'b1/c1' do not work on that node! So I try an experiment. The same node that not work with my pattern I converted back to XML and than in a node. And now the xpath pattern work like on the online xpath test page. Why? Its the sam XML.

Answer (score 0):

> I want make a list of  nodes and then get the id-value of the node.

So, that is to say, you want to make a list of the id attribute values?

```js
var DOMParser = require("xmldom").DOMParser;
var xpath = require("xpath");

let data = `<start>
    <b1 id="111"><c1 id="333">ccc</c1></b1>
    <b1 id="222">bbb</b1>
</start>`

let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data);

let ids = xpath.select("//b1/@id", doc).map(attr => attr.value);
// -> ["333", "222"]
```

An alternative to the last line is this:

```
let ids = xpath.select("//b1", doc).map(node => node.getAttribute('id'));
// -> ["333", "222"]
```

Comment: I only want find nodes on absolute path b1/c1 not on relativ //b1/c1. Releativ patter find more as I want in my real XML. Try the absolute xpath on the test page. It work fine. Why not on subnodes from xpath.select?

Comment: @Gerd For one thing, `b1/c1` is the relative path and `//b1/c1` is the absolute one. But more importantly you must reduce your problem complexity. You don't need most of the steps you have tried, and trying to fix unexpected behavior in code that you are not going to use is somewhat a waste of time.